# Silent push in kiosk mode

Tags: ios, mdm, kiosk, kiosk-mode, silentpush

I have a supervised device with few apps installed on it. I change the device into Kiosk mode to run the Web browser App. 
Now when the device is in the kiosk mode I push a silent notification to another app on the device using following payload:
{
    "aps" : {
        "content-available" : 1
    },
    "message" : "newmessage"
}

What happens in this scenario?
Does kiosk mode allow any other app to receive silent push?

Comment: If you ever find out the answer, do post back here.